# How to make one action event for many chechbox'es?

Tags: java, events, javafx

I create an application in JavaFX where there is a lot of choicebox'es (around 100). Clicking each of them changes the status of one Boolean variable (selected - true, unselected - false). I have ActionEvent for each of choicebox, but I would like to make action event which suport all of them.

One of ActionEvent looks like:

```
public void onActionClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(firstCheckbox.isSelected()){
        firstBooleanValue=true;
    } else {
        firstBooleanValue=false;
    }
}
```

Second looks similar:

```
public void onActionClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(secondCheckbox.isSelected()){
        secondBooleanValue=true;
    } else {
        secondBooleanValue=false;
    }
}
```

I heard from my friend that I should create class with EventHandler and pass parameters (Checkbox and Boolean variable) but I don't know how. Any solutions?

Comment: Wondering if you really have one `boolean` field for every `CheckBox`? Why not just use the `selected` property of the `CheckBox`es directly?

Comment: I would suggest you create a list of those checkboxes and their values, with an index equal to the ID of the button. Then loop over them and create your handler with setOnAction and pass the caller (checkbox) in the eventhandler. When the event is raised you can get the caller with foo.getSource() and retrieve the ID from it to access your list and set the new value of your checkbox, which is simply: value = foo.isSelected().. No need for an if.. else to get true or false and assign it to one variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I heard from my friend that I should create class with EventHandler and pass parameters (Checkbox and Boolean variable)

Unless you want to use a container class for the `boolean` variable (e.g. `BooleanProperty`), it's not really possible to pass a variable in a way that allows you to write it. You could of course pass a `Consumer<Boolean>`.

(Theoretically it would be possible to access fields via reflection to write a value, but I strongly recommend not doing this.)

In the event handler you could use the `source` property to get the object that triggered the change (the `CheckBox`). This fact would allow you to create a `Map<CheckBox, Consumer<Boolean>>` to handle the event with the same event handler without testing for reference equality with 100 `CheckBox`es.

```
private boolean a;
private boolean b;
private boolean c;
private Map<CheckBox, Consumer<Boolean>> eventMap = new HashMap<>();

private void comboAction(ActionEvent event) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
    eventMap.get(cb).accept(cb.isSelected());
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox("a");
    CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox("b");
    CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox("c");

    // tell event handler what to do with the booleans
    eventMap.put(cb1, v -> a = v);
    eventMap.put(cb2, v -> b = v);
    eventMap.put(cb3, v -> c = v);

    // register event handlers
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> onAction = this::comboAction;

    for (CheckBox cb : eventMap.keySet()) {
        cb.setOnAction(onAction);
    }

    Button button = new Button("print");
    button.setOnAction(evt -> {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println("-------");
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(cb1, cb2, cb3, button));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

However the fact that there are 100 boolean fields in a single class indicates a design issue. Consider storing the data in a different data structure, like `List`, `Map` or similar data structures. You could also store the `CheckBox`es in such a data structure which would make the use of an `onAction` event handler unnecessary; you could simply retrieve the `CheckBox` responsible for the property and use `isSelected` when you need the value...